# How to use expectOutputString PHPunits?

Tags: phpunit, tdd, fat-free-framework

this my first question.

I install composer (1.10.5), fatfree-core(3.7) and phpunit (9.1.3) and go to TDD.

All working, but if i use $this->expectOutputString();
I've Assertions: 0 - not working.

I found it's:

```
> $f3 = Base::instance();
> 
> $f3 -> mock ('GET /'); // <= it is problem
```

```
    <?php 
    [...]
    protected function setUp (): void
        {
            $this->f3 = Base::instance ();
            $this->f3 -> set ('QUIET',TRUE);
            $this->f3 -> config ('config.ini');
            $this->f3 -> mock ('GET /ftp');

            $this -> MainController = new MainController ($this->f3);
        }

        public function testExpectFooActualFoo ()
        {
            $this->expectOutputString ('foo');
            print'foo';
        }
    [...]
```

CMD:

```
 @php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit tests/MainControllerNoStaticTest.php
 PHPUnit 9.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

 fooR
                        1 / 1 (100%)

 Time: 00:00.052, Memory: 4.00 MB

 There was 1 risky test:

 1) MainControllerNoStaticTest::testExpectFooActualFoo
 Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.
```

Base heve finall class, before I mocked myself i edit base core and delete finall, but now this not good idea. Base (fat-free) have mock option.

Do you have an idea how to get it to be good?
- without modifying fat-free and phpunit files?
I want to use phpunit for testing, and I put the programming environment on fat-free.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getActualOutputForAssertion()` to get the output and then use regular assertions on its return value. This will not help you, though, with misbehaving code under test that does not (only) close its own output buffers.

Comment: Wow @SebastianBergmann, i know who you are. thx
`var_dump($this->getActualOutputForAssertion() )` return string (0) "",
but I read, I have a lead.
Before I use `ob_start();` and `ob_get_contents()` but in console is not working: